# How do i automatically update my table based on month filters

Tags: vba, excel-2010

the table in the image has a 12 month period overview, in this case from FEB 2018 to JAN 2019. And come next month, the table will be updated and as a result start from MAR 2018 to FEB 2019, APR 2018 to MAR 2019 and so on.  The table is currently updated manually every month. Given the current month, I’m going to have to go back and filter data for previous months all the way to the month before the current month. How do I get to automatically update it such that month filters of previous months change when the macro changes the column whilst in the process of updating the table?. So far the macro below allows me to move from within this range (C14:N19) but as you will see, the filter is hard-coded and not dynamic. Any help will highly be appreciated

`Sub LUUUP()`

`Dim i As Long`
`i = 0`
`For x = 1 To 12`
`i = i + 1`

```
    If x = 1 Then y = "C"
    If x = 2 Then y = "D"
    If x = 3 Then y = "E"
    If x = 4 Then y = "F"
    If x = 5 Then y = "G"
    If x = 6 Then y = "H"
    If x = 7 Then y = "I"
    If x = 8 Then y = "J"
    If x = 9 Then y = "K"
    If x = 10 Then y = "L"
    If x = 11 Then y = "M"
    If x = 12 Then y = "N"
```

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
        xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic`

`Range("C1").Copy`
`Sheets("feuil1").Select`

`Range(y & "14").Select`
`Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False`

`Next x`
`End Sub`

Comment: You can do this with a formula. Just adjust the year and offset as needed:  `=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MOD(COLUMN(),12) + 1, 1),"mmmm")`

Comment: Thanks Comintern, but it actually doesn't do it because my request wasn't clear enough.